# how to call function in parent window when closing child window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent window and a child window. I want to call a function when closing the child window .
The code of parent window is below:

```
function Button4_onclick(){
newWin=window.open("http://10.10.19.22:8086/childwindow.jsp");
newWin.onunload = updatet();  
}

function updatet()
{
  if(newWin.location != "about:blank"){
  document.getElementById("SerialNumber24").value='2345';
}
```

But this code not work and the function is called when opening the child window instead. So which event listener can I use for closing ? Thx.

Comment: You are calling the function and assigning what it returns to the event listener! `newWin.onunload = updatet();` should be `newWin.onunload = updatet;`

Answer (score 0):

That is possible if you own the child window. You need to set event `onbeforeunload` on the child.

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/itgoldman/9mafwu2L/33/

```
window.foo = function foo() {
  alert("hello i am parent")
}

function open_window() {
  var win = window.open("", "Title", "toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=600,height=200,top=" + (screen.height - 400) + ",left=" + (screen.width - 840));
  if (!win) {
    alert("window open was blocked");
    return;
  }
  win.document.write(str);
  win.window.parent = this;
}

var script = `
window.onbeforeunload = function(ev) {
    window.parent.foo();
  return;
}
`;
var str = '<scri' + 'pt>' + script + '</scr' + 'ipt><h1>close me</h1>'
```